# DatePicher is not working in phonegap application

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, cordova

I am developing android application using eclipse ADT  phonegap, when i select date ,no calender popup.   thank you in advance.........

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
  <h1>Text Inputs</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
      <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="fullname">Full name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname">       
        <label for="bday">Date of Birth:</label>
        <input type="date" name="bday" id="bday">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email..">
      </div>
      <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: some android versions (most of them in fact) don't support the date picker

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but basically  is not working in Internet explorer and Mozilla . i try with chrome and it will work perfectly.and phone gap basically depend on browser.And I don't know about it so much. so sorry for that.

Phone Gap (Cordova) currently uses the standard Android WebView which is a stripped down version of a browser (based on a particular version of WebKit).

It can't really be the Chromium-based WebView yet, that was just made available as a component to third party developers only recently in Android 4.4.

And as of April 1st 2014, Android 4.4 (KitKat) constitutes only about 5.3% of all the Android versions (not to mention, this new Chromium-based WebView still seems to be a work in progress, so it will take a while for most third party developers to feel completely comfortable with it).

```
jsfiddle.net/4r9mopwr/embedded/result/

Open it with chrome

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_date.asp
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, jQuery UI Datepicker widget combined with a 3rd party wrapper to make this work with jQuery Mobile, so you need to combine jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper js and css in your page from here **https://github.com/arschmitz/jquery-mobile-datepicker-wrapper**, then in html

```
<input type="text" class="date-input">

<script>
  $(function(){
     $( ".date-input" ).datepicker();
 })
</script>
```